# Hot key changed

Tags: modeling

[image]

At the top right of the screen, where you change between object, edit and other modes, I used to be able to use the top row numbers on the keyboard to change between edge, vertex and face mode. Now the top row numbers do the same thing as if I were using my number pad and change position of the object. What did I do to change this and how do I change it back? This is on my laptop, the workstation hot keys work like they are suppose to.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Edit > Preferences > Input > Emulate Numpad. Uncheck this option.
[image]